# invalid JSON to monitor SMART on Zabbix

Tags: zabbix, github, json, smartctl, autodiscovery

I've followed these steps on github: https://github.com/v-zhuravlev/zbx-smartctl to monitor the SMART disks in my Winsows servers on Zabbix. BUt when I add the template to the host I'd configured, on the frontend, it shows me this error as "not supported":

Invalid discovery rule value: cannot parse as a valid JSON object: invalid object format, expected opening character '{' or '[' at: 'Falha ao processar -File '"C:\Program': Caracteres inv?lidos no caminho. Especifique um caminho v?lido para o par?metro -File.'

How can I fix this?